# Show last 5 opened processes in terminal?

Tags: terminal, ps, watch

I am trying to have a terminal showing the last 5 processes opened. This is helpful for my debugging.

At this point I have

```
watch ps -ef --sort=start_time
```

This works fine but it shows all processes so they don't fit in the screen. How can I limit it to a specific number like 5 or 10?

-- Update --

A have tried

```
watch "ps -ef --sort=start_time | tail -n 5"
```

but the problem is that the header of `ps` is omitted so after a while I don't know what I am looking at.

Comment: `watch ps -ef --sort=start_time | head -5` or `watch ps -ef --sort=start_time | tail -5` depending on whether the sort is ascending or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
watch "ps -ef --sort=start_time | tail -n 5"
```

`tail` will only output the last `n` lines piped to it.

I assume you tried:

```
watch ps -ef --sort=start_time | tail -n 5
```

Which would try and pipe the output of `watch` to `tail`, rather than the output of `ps`, and as `watch` never terminates, `tail` can't determine when the last `n` lines are output, so also prints nothing.

---

If you wish to keep the header as well, you can use some clever bash to simply:

```
watch "ps -ef --sort=start_time | (head -n 1 ; tail -n 5)"
```

Which causes `head` to print the top line as well.

Comment: I tried this. The problem is that the header line is then omitted. Would prefer if I could keep the header..

Comment: Apologies, I fell into the exact pitfall I mentioned in the middle of my post, try now!

Comment: The combination of **head** and **tail** on a single pipe does not work reliably, but only if the **ps** output is longer than **head**'s input buffer (try `watch "ps -f --sort=start_time | (head -n 1 ; tail -n 5)"` to see what I mean). To make sure that both programs see all the output, you need to use a temporary file, eg `watch "ps -ef --sort=start_time >TempFile; head -n 1 <TempFile ; tail -n 5 <TempFile"` (you could also use **tee** to create _tempFile_). Both **-f** and **-ef** now show the last five lines.